# bash if equals some file

Tags: bash, if-statement, operators

I have a scripts that serves as a kill switch for another script. It compares the value of a file "kill.txt" of either a "0" or "1".

```
echo "KILL SWITCH: $(< /path/to/file/kill.txt)"
if [[ $(< /path/to/file/kill.txt) == 1 ]]; then
    echo "kill-switch engaged"
else
    echo "kill-switch NOT engaged"
fi
```

When "kill.txt" is saved to 1, the echo of the file outputs as 1 but the terminal outputs `kill-switch NOT engaged` when it should output `kill-switch engaged`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me. Make sure there isn't any extra whitespace in the file.

Comment: Instead of reading the file contents, a common strategy is just to use the file's existence as the switch.

Comment: `if [ -f /path/to/kill.txt ]`

Comment: Then you use `touch kill.txt` to engage, `rm kill.txt` to disengage.

Comment: `echo` is not a good tool for showing the value of a variable.  The best way to see an unambiguous representation of the value of a variable is to use `declare -p var`.  In this case try `kill_switch=$(< /path/to/file/kill.txt); declare -p kill_switch`

Comment: A *very* common cause of problems like this is that the file has Windows-style (CR-LF) line endings.  See the "Before asking about problematic code" section of the [Stack Overflow 'bash' Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).  Also see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/4154375).

Comment: @pjh But he does not `echo` any variable.